# Less files not loaded on FIPS mode

Tags: less, fips

Once the FIPS mode enabled on the web server, the less files are not loaded on the client browser, getting 500 error.

I am not sure if LESS compiler uses any managed cryptography algorithms.

Need help if anyone already enabled FIPS mode with LESS.

This is the same case for jquery resource files too.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

IIS application pool is running on default identity for hosting projects. Once FIPS enabled, this identity somehow not running properly and not allowing application pool run and provide results.

Once adding service account in domain tie that with application pool it started working correctly and provides all necessary files requested by any browser.